# copy from windows machine to linux

Tags: windows, linux

I have a dir which I can access from my windows machine goes like `\\servername\directory` and I can see all the files in there, is it possible that I can wget or something those files inside this directory to my remote linux machine, both of these windows and linux machines are remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option is to use [Samba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) to access the Windows share from your Linux system.

On most modern Linux systems, you can mount a samba share as:

```
mount '//servername/directory' /mnt -o 'user=mydomain\myusername'
```

(note the single quotation marks, and that the backslashes in the server designation are converted to forward slashes). The last part "-o..." is optional, only necessary if you need to authenticate to the share, then you need to specify logon domain+username. You will then be prompted for a password.

Most Linux systems also have a graphical way to access this (e.g. network display in Ubuntu).

After mounting, the remote directory will appear like a local directory to you.

If this does not work for you, please edit your question with more details.